# Why is scanf() skipped?

Tags: c, scanf

Could you explain why only the first `scanf()` is working but others are skipped? This happens in every code I write on my PC but works on other computers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    float interest, principal, rate;
    int days;

    while(true)
    {
        if(principal == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter loan principal (Enter -1 to end): \n");
        scanf("%.2f", &principal);

        printf("Enter interest rate: \n");
        scanf("%.2f", &rate);
        printf("Enter term of the loan in days: \n");
        scanf("%d", &days);
    }
}
```

the output:

```
Enter loan principal (Enter -1 to end): 
-1
Enter interest rate: 
Enter term of the loan in days:
Enter loan principal (Enter -1 to end)
```

Comment: For starters, you need to check `scanf()`'s return value to see if it succeeded.

Comment: You're writing the interest rate into principal. Are you sure you mean to do this ?

Comment: Not related to `scanf`, but you don't initialize `principal` before you check it for `-1`.

Comment: What do you mean "are skipped"? Also, you're doing `scanf("%.2f", &principal);` twice. I think the second one was meant to be `scanf("%.2f", &rate);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of scanf is invalid. You can not use .2f because the "." modifier is not supported. Please fix this code

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  float interest, principal, rate;
  int days;

  while (true) {
    if (principal == -1) {
      break;
    }
    printf("Enter loan principal (Enter -1 to end): \n");
    scanf("%2f", &principal);

    printf("Enter interest rate: \n");
    scanf("%2f", &rate);
    printf("Enter term of the loan in days: \n");
    scanf("%d", &days);
  }
}
```

Comment: In which cases .1f .2f used?

Comment: @Muhammad Koziev a printf() family function could use those format specifiers.